# Uploaded Excel files tmp_name is only empty sometimes

Tags: php, html, excel, file-upload

So I found an error in my uploader function, which I've been using for some time now. But today when I uploaded a excel file with some `tables etc. in notes`, `tmp_name` was empty. The file is only 2.3kB and when I try with a older file 11kB in size it works perfectly.

I tried to print the array and it had the following:

```php
Array ( [xml_file] => Array ( [name] => export_test.xlsx [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )
```

Can a formatted cell with `notes` or something like that make it not upload?
[image]

When I upload the 11kB file I get the following, which is right:

```php
Array ( [xml_file] => Array ( [name] => export (3).xlsx [type] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php39F3.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 53226 ) )
```

The HTML/PHP form I use is this:

```
<form name="form" style="display: inline-block; width: 80%;" method="post" action="../Test/DashboardFiles/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input-group">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="xml_file" accept=".xl*" class="btn custom-file-input" id="f02">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="f02">Choose file</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                    <input style="border-radius: .35rem !important;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary formClickResetUrl" id="uploadRVTM" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" disabled/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="project" value="
                                                                <?php
                                                                if (isset($_GET['Project'])) {
                                                                    echo $_GET['Project'][0];
                                                                }else{
                                                                    echo $FirstItemDD[0][0];
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                            ">
                <script>
                    typefile();
                </script>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And inside the *upload.php* I move the file around if it exists etc. but let's just say it contains only `print_r($_FILES);`

The temporary files is saved in `C:\xampp\tmp` changed inside my `php.ini` and max upload size is `upload_max_filesize=2M`

Comment: `[error] => 1` means `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` - "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini." https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php It is quite unlikely that PHP would lie about that.

Comment: _"Can a formatted cell with notes or something like that make it not upload?"_ - not per se; but if the amount of data in those cells (resp. rather the data that gets actually send), _plus_ the upload file size, hits `post_max_size`, then the whole request would also not succeed.

Comment: @CBroe The funny thing is when I save the correct same file as `2003` is says `some feature might be lost....` I still tried, and now it can upload that file too. Which feature blocks it from uploading I don't know..  post_max_size = `post_max_size=8M`

Comment: Any "features" contained in an Excel file can't really have any influence on the uploading part itself (unless you had some sort of server firewall running, that inspects the POST body and looks for "malicious" stuff.)

Comment: @CBroe It isn't due to firewall, tried to turn it off but still get the error. BUT I tried to increase the `upload_max_filesize to 12M` and now it works. But this also makes great sense... my file was 2300kB not 2.3kB. One thing I don't know is why my 11000kB file can be uploaded then?` What `upload_max_filesize` size would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve your server's resources, hosts set a limit on the maximum size of a file that can be uploaded. This maximum, in megabytes, is defined in the `upload_max_filesize` directive.

Changed `upload_max_filesize=2M` to `upload_max_filesize=15M`

Change this setting inside the `php.ini`

[image]